# Can I get Intellij Idea 10.5 to do code completion on model variables in a shared GSP template?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, code-completion

****Edit**** I didn't know about 'Add Dynamic Property' feature of Idea, that is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks Sergey

I love the fact how Intelli-J recognizes the type of variables put into the model from a common controller and allows autocomplete right in the GSP.

For example if I have a controller method

```
def mymethod = {          
  MyDomain myDomainInstance = 
.... logic ...
[myDomainInstance: myDomainInstance]
```

}

In my corresponding mymethod.gsp, Intelli-J will autocomplete methods on ${myDomainInstance} from the MyDomain bean.

However consider a shared template that uses the same domain class and could be rendered via

```
<g:render template="/shared/somesharedtemplate" model="['myDomainInstance': myDomainInstance]">
```

When I am editing /shared/_somesharedtemplate.gsp, ${myDomainInstance} is not recognized as something Intelli-J knows about (but of course works fine when Grails runs).  Is there any declaration or anything I can add to the GSP to hint it?

Comment: In regular groovy code I sometimes type the object which helps out intellisense.  So maybe try something like: <% MyDomain instance = myDomainInstance %> Then referencing instance.  I wouldn't classify that as good general advice, but it might help you get intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove quotes around variable name in value of 'model' attribute. IDEA does not recognize model variable defined inside quotes. It's a bug: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-80041.

Also you can add a dynamic property 'myDomainInstance' for page _somesharedtemplate.gsp . Press Alt+Enter on unrecognized reference then select 'Add Dynamic Property 'myDomainInstance'' intention.

Comment: first suggestion didn't help (it kind of makes sense that it didn't, as what if you called the shared template from more than one place, with different types of variable?  It would be programatically silly, but legal, and how would Idea know?), but that 'add dynamic property' is exactly what I was looking for.